# how to change color in php based on a function?

Tags: php, function

I know there are similar topics but I couldn't figure out how to swap it.

I need to change color from what it is to RED depending on my function

What I used so far was :

**This is my function**

```
    <?php
function getHolidays($year = null) {
        if ($year == null) {
            $year = intval(date('Y'));
        }

        $easterDate = easter_date($year);
        $easterDay = date('j', $easterDate);
        $easterMonth = date('n', $easterDate);
        $easterYear = date('Y', $easterDate);

        $holidays = array(
            // These days have a fixed date
            date("m-d-Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $year)),
            date("m-d-Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 6, $year)),
            date("m-d-Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, 4, 25, $year)),
            date("m-d-Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, 5, 1, $year)),
            date("m-d-Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, 6, 2, $year)),
            date("m-d-Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, 6, 29, $year)),
            date("m-d-Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, 8, 15, $year)),
            date("m-d-Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, 11, 1, $year)),
            date("m-d-Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 8, $year)),
            date("m-d-Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 25, $year)),
            date("m-d-Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 28, $year)),
            // These days have a date depending on easter
            date("m-d-Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $easterMonth, $easterDay + 1, $easterYear)),
        );

        sort($holidays);
        return $holidays;
    }

    function holidays_color ($date) {
        $holidays = getHolidays();
        $weekend = date('w', strtotime($date));

        if (in_array($date, $holidays)) {
            return "<th color= \"red \">";
        } else if ($weekend == 0 || $weekend == 6) {
            return "<th color= \"red \">";
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } ?>
```

Then I created a table to show all days of a month now based on (holidays_color) function I need to change color of holidays and weekends .

**This is my table**

```
<?php    
echo "<table class=\"table table-bordered \" id=\"main_table\">";
                    echo"<TH>Nome utente</TH>";
                    // creat days of month in table header
                     $lastday = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, date("m"), date("Y"));
                    for ($day = 1; $day <= $lastday; $day++) {
                       holidays_color ($day . "-" . date("m") . "-" . date("Y") );
                        echo"<TH>";
                        echo  $day ;
                        echo "</TH>";
                    }
                    echo"<TH> Option </TH>";  echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: what is $lastday here

Comment: Sorry i forgot that one :// Last day in a month 
 $lastday = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, date("m"), date("Y"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code please correct them..you are checking the holidays color with d-m-y format but function is in m-d-Y format..

```
for ($day = 1; $day <= $lastday; $day++) {  
            echo holidays_color(date("m"). "-" .$day. "-" .date("Y"));
                        echo  $day ;
                        echo "</TH>";
                    }
```

And change function holidays to some thing like this and let me know is this what your expecting output

```
function holidays_color ($date) {

        $holidays = getHolidays();
        $weekend = date('w', strtotime($date));

        if (in_array($date, $holidays)) {
            return "<th style='color:red'>";
        } else if ($weekend == 0 || $weekend == 6) {
            return "<th style='color:red'>";
        } else {
            return "<th>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is your expected output I mean which dates to be in red color

Comment: no ... MY bad ... Sorry ... its working ... i just change it like this  :: echo holidays_color($day .  "-" .date("m"). "-" .date("Y"));